# I want to echo something at compile time.But it doesn't work for a cross compiler

Tags: gcc, makefile, ubuntu-14.04, cross-compiling

I am working on a cross-compiler. I tried:

```
all: 

; $(info $$var is [${var}])echo Hello world
```

But nothing is printed after running

```
$ make install
```

Instead a new file `Makefile~` is created.

What should I do?

Comment: Read some documentation or a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Try using @echo in the Makefile, which will suppress the echoing line and discards '@' before sending the line to the shell.

Typically you would use this for a command whose only effect is to print something, such as an echo command to indicate progress through the makefile.